# Ruby Grape: json output is escaped

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am working on a sample Ruby / Grape example, and everything works except the json is served escaped. I am brand new too ruby and its frameworks (just 3 days), so sorry if this question is remedial and thhank you in advance

I am fairly certain there shouldn't be escaping of the quotes, anyhow here is the escaped output:

```
"{\"word\":\"test\",\"sentiment\":\"unkown\"}"
```

my code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'grape'
require 'json'

class SentimentApiV1  < Grape::API
  version 'v1', :using => :path, :vendor => '3scale'
  format :json

  resource :words do
    get ':word' do
        {:word => params[:word], :sentiment => "unkown"}.to_json
    end

    post ':word' do
      {:word => params[:word], :result => "thinking"}.to_json
    end 
  end

  resource :sentences do
    get ':sentence' do
      {:sentence => params[:sentence], :result => "unkown"}.to_json
    end
  end

end
```

config.ru

> $:.unshift "./app"
>
> require 'sentimentapi_v1.rb'
>
> run SentimentApiV1

Packages and versions

```
C:\Ruby-Projects\GrapeTest>bundle install
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.7.7)
Using atomic (1.1.10)
Using thread_safe (0.1.0)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activesupport (4.0.0)
Using backports (3.3.3)
Using builder (3.2.2)
Using daemons (1.1.9)
Using descendants_tracker (0.0.1)
Using hashie (2.0.5)
Using multi_xml (0.5.4)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-accept (0.4.5)
Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
Using virtus (0.5.5)
Using grape (0.5.0)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using thin (1.5.1)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
```

I am running ruby 2.0, grape .5, windows 8 64bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason the escaping is happening is because you don't need the `#to_json` call at the end because on line 7 you are specifying `format :json` as the output format.

Answer (score 1):

well - apparently the to_json is not needed at the end.  perhaps a double escaping or something like that.  The demo definitely had the to_json in there, so there's that.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'grape'
require 'json'

class SentimentApiV1  < Grape::API
  version 'v1', :using => :path, :vendor => '3scale'
  format :json

  resource :words do
    get ':word' do
        {:word => params[:word], :sentiment => "unkown"}
    end

    post ':word' do
      {:word => params[:word], :result => "thinking"}
    end 
  end

  resource :sentences do
    get ':sentence' do
      {:sentence => params[:sentence], :result => "unkown"}
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your result, `"{\"word\":\"test\",\"sentiment\":\"unkown\"}"` is actually valid JSON. It's the string `{"word":"test","sentiment":"unkown"}`. By calling `to_json`, you have converted your hash to a String, then Grape will return what you gave it. Use `as_json` instead that will return a hash, and Grape will take care of serializing it properly.